# fadeIn and fadeOut flickering if scrolling is fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, scrolltop

I have this script which fades in an element when I scroll more than 145px from the top.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 145) {
$('#fademenu').fadeIn();
}
else {
$('#fademenu').fadeOut();
}

});
```

Works fine. The only problem is that when I quickly scroll to the top and then back down and back top (etc) it continues fading in and out also after I stopped scrolling (executes all the fades in/out). How can I deal with this (prevent the continuous fade in/out)? [DEMO](http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must clear the jQuery animation queue each time. Try this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 145) {
$('#fademenu').stop().fadeIn();
}
else {
$('#fademenu').stop().fadeOut();
}

});
```